How to get personal correspondence with a user outside the guild using the discord py correspondence id
I need to get a message in a conversation with a user that already exists, but I ran into the problem that I can't get the conversation as an object by id, although the id is correct
Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'
async def updatePost(userId, channelId, messageId):
    print("Проверка")
    user = await bot.fetch_user(userId)
    print(channelId)
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(channelId))
    print(channel)
    print(messageId)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(messageId)

I have already tried to enter id as a constant, but the error is still the same: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

The solution to the problem is to get dm_channel as an object, you first need to send some kind of message to the user, without this, as I understand it, the channel is closed and therefore it does not give access
async def updatePost(userId, channelId, messageId):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(userId)
    messageUp = await user.send("Обновление данных")
    channel = user.dm_channel
    print(channel)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(messageId)
    await messageUp.delete()
    if user.id == 485463652040704000:
        my_view = ViewAdmin(user=user)
    else:
        my_view = ViewClient(user=user)
    await message.edit(view=my_view)

